# String accessor is causing the string to be an int C++

Tags: c++, string, accessor, nfa

I am attempting to code an NFA in C++ that can recognize a string and determines if that string is accepted or rejected. I have the string input that is going to be evaluated coming in as a string.

However, once I go to access it in the evaluateInput() function (within the third nested for loop, the if statement) for some reason the program will not compile because it says that in.at(i) is considered an int so it cannot be compared to the string.

I am confused as to why throughout the program it is a string, but when it is accessed it suddenly becomes an int?

I get the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and
      'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >'))
                                if(in[i] == currStates[j].transitions[k].symb)
```

I have provided all of my code if it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string num, SoA1, SoA2, currentState, symbol, tranState;

struct Transition;

struct State{
    bool startS = false;
    bool acceptS = false;
    string sym;
    vector<Transition> transitions;//transition between states
};

struct Transition{
    string symb;
    State to;
    State from;
};

struct NFA{
    vector<State> NFAStates;
    State start;
};

void evaluateInput(string in, NFA F)
{

    vector<State> currStates;
    currStates.push_back(F.start);

    if(in[1] == "1")
    {
        cout << "yes" << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
    {
        cout << "input #: " << in[i] << endl;
        vector<State> next;
        for(int j = 0; j < currStates.size(); j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < currStates[j].transitions.size(); k++)
            {
                if(in.at(i) == currStates[j].transitions[k].symb)
                {
                    next.push_back(currStates[j].transitions[k].to);
                }
            }
        }
        currStates = next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* fileName;
    string stringInput;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        fileName = argv[1];
        stringInput = argv[2];
        //cout << stringInput << endl;
    }

    ifstream file(fileName);

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        NFA FA;
        string line;
        while(getline(file, line)){
            //cout << "1: " << line << endl;
            string ST;

            stringstream ss(line);
            getline(ss, ST, '\t');

            if(ST == "state")
            {
                State S;
                getline(ss, num, '\t');
                getline(ss, SoA1, '\t');
                getline(ss, SoA2);

                int num_i = stoi(num);
                S.sym = num_i;
                if((SoA1 == "start") || (SoA2 == "start"))
                {
                    S.startS = true;
                }

                if((SoA1 == "accept") || (SoA2 == "accept"))
                {
                    S.acceptS = true;
                }

                FA.NFAStates.push_back(S);
                if(S.startS == true){
                    FA.start = S;
                }
            }else if(ST == "transition")
            {
                Transition T;
                getline(ss, currentState, '\t');
                getline(ss, symbol, '\t');
                getline(ss, tranState);

                int currentState_i = stoi(currentState);
                int tranState_i = stoi(tranState);
                T.symb = symbol;

                for(int j = 0; j < FA.NFAStates.size(); j++)
                {
                    if(FA.NFAStates[j].sym == tranState)
                    {
                        T.to = FA.NFAStates[j];
                    }
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < FA.NFAStates.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(FA.NFAStates[i].sym == currentState)
                    {
                        T.from = FA.NFAStates[i];
                        FA.NFAStates[i].transitions.push_back(T);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        evaluateInput(stringInput, FA);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Think about it for a minute.  What is `in`?  What does `at` return when it is called on `in`?  This may help you [`std::basic_string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at)

Comment: You're accessing a single character in a string. `at` will return a `char`, which is promoted to `int`.

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings and pay attention to them! Fix one warning after the other, without using any casts.

Comment: It may seem counter-intuitive but you can't compare a single `char` to a string, unless that single char is inside a string. You have a similar problem with your `if(in[1] == "1")` you need to compare against a `char` not a string: `if(in[1] == '1')` (single quotes, not double).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix it by making the symbol a single char.

Comment: @Cornstalks it's not promoted to int here according to the C++ Standard ; the compiler message is somewhat bogus